Microsoft 365 Dev Program, user data pack never finishes
After starting the installation of the user data pack in a M365 Developer sandbox, the install does not finish. The spinner keeps on turning with the message "Installing. This is taking longer than usual..."
Instructed to refresh page - no effect. Been waiting for 3+ hrs now. Anyone know how to fix?
Thx in advance for help and/or pointers!
